# Accessing MKLocalSearchResponse item (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, mklocalsearch

When I do `println(localSearchResponse)`, I get a MapItem object, which includes a ton of details about the location. In this example, its UCSD.  Here is the output showing in my log.

```
<MKLocalSearchResponse: 0x1c53d640> {
    boundingRegion = "<center:+32.87514836, -117.23958822 span:+0.00725621, +0.00825332>";
    mapItems =     (
        "<MKMapItem: 0x1c538090> {\n    isCurrentLocation = 0;\n    name = \"University of California, San Diego\";\n    phoneNumber = \"+18585342230\";\n    placemark = \"University of California, San Diego, 9500 Gilman Dr, La Jolla, CA  92093-5004, United States @ <+32.87529400,-117.23961000> +/- 0.00m, region CLCircularRegion (identifier:'<+32.87514837,-117.23958825> radius 557.57', center:<+32.87514837,-117.23958825>, radius:557.57m)\";\n    url = \"http://www.ucsd.edu\";\n}"
    );
}
```

Notice how it outputs `placemark = University of California...` and has the address?  How do I get this value and store it into a variable?  Here is my code:

```
localSearchRequest = MKLocalSearchRequest()
localSearchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = addressTextField.text
localSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: localSearchRequest)
localSearch.startWithCompletionHandler { (localSearchResponse, error) -> Void in

    if localSearchResponse == nil{
        var alert = UIAlertView(title: nil, message: "Place not found", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Try again")
        alert.show()
        return
    }

    //prints the MKLocalSearchResponse with name, phoneNumber, placemark
    println(localSearchResponse)

    //Get latitude and longitude
    var newRecordLat = localSearchResponse.boundingRegion.center.latitude
    var newRecordLong = localSearchResponse.boundingRegion.center.longitude

    //How do I get the address, which is "placemark" in the MKLocalSearchResponse?
    var newRecordAddress = localSearchResponse.mapItems...???

    //store values to Parse
    self.latToParse = newRecordLat
    self.longToParse = newRecordLong
}
```

Here is the documentation of [MKSearchResponse](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKLocalSearchResponse_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKLocalSearchResponse/mapItems)

And here is the documentation of [MKMapItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapItem_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapItem/phoneNumber)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

```
var newRecordAddress = (localSearchResponse.mapItems[0] as! MKMapItem).placemark
```

This object contains all information you need. Checked it in demo project

Address only:

```
var newRecordAddress = (localSearchResponse.mapItems[0] as! MKMapItem).placemark
let addressOnly = newRecordAddress.name + ", " + newRecordAddress.title
```

`newRecordAddress.name` is place's name
`newRecordAddress.title` is place's address you required

Comment: Thank you.  It returns: "5190 Leo St, 5190 Leo St, San Diego, CA  92115-1535, United States @ <+32.77302200,-117.05744500> +/- 0.00m, region CLCircularRegion (identifier:'<+32.77301170,-117.05740795> radius 18.87', center:<+32.77301170,-117.05740795>, radius:18.87m)".  Do you know how to get the address only?  Or, "5190 Leo St, San Diego, Ca 92115-1535"?

Comment: If you can answer that I will reward for bounty.

Comment: I can do it tomorrow morning

Comment: THANK YOU.  This is a crucial aspect to my project, and was worried I had to find another way around this, until you saved the say.  Thank you Max Power!

Comment: btw bounty is still not given :)

Comment: sorry!  I am new to stack, I thought if I checked it as correct it was given.  Did you receive it?

Answer (score 0):

Because `mapItems` is an array, you need to call `first` to access the first element of that array. This will return an `MKMapItem`, so you can get the placemark property with this code:

```
localSearchResponse.mapItems.first.placemark
```

Comment: Hi Glorfindel.  I tried doing that, and came up with an error: 'placemark' is unavailable: APIs deprecated as of ios7 and earlier are unavailable in Swift

Comment: Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31488686/accessing-mklocalsearchresponse-item-swift