# MKMapItem placemark in MKLocalSearchResponse is deprecated(swift)

Tags: ios, swift

When I do `println(localSearchResponse)`, I get a MapItem object, which includes a ton of details about the location. In this example, its UCSD.  Here is the output showing in my log.

```
    <MKLocalSearchResponse: 0x1c53d640> {
boundingRegion = "<center:+32.87514836, -117.23958822 span:+0.00725621, +0.00825332>";
mapItems =     (
    "<MKMapItem: 0x1c538090> {\n    isCurrentLocation = 0;\n    name = \"University of California, San Diego\";\n    phoneNumber = \"+18585342230\";\n    placemark = \"University of California, San Diego, 9500 Gilman Dr, La Jolla, CA  92093-5004, United States @ <+32.87529400,-117.23961000> +/- 0.00m, region CLCircularRegion (identifier:'<+32.87514837,-117.23958825> radius 557.57', center:<+32.87514837,-117.23958825>, radius:557.57m)\";\n    url = \"http://www.ucsd.edu\";\n}"
);
}
```

Notice how it outputs `placemark = University of California...` and has the address?  How do I get this value and store it into a variable?  I tried localSearchResponse.mapItems.first.placemark and it generated an error: "error: 'placemark' is unavailable: APIs deprecated as of ios7 and earlier are unavailable in Swift"

 
Here is my code:

```
    localSearchRequest = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    localSearchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = addressTextField.text
    localSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: localSearchRequest)
    localSearch.startWithCompletionHandler { (localSearchResponse, error) -> Void in

        if localSearchResponse == nil{
            var alert = UIAlertView(title: nil, message: "Place not found", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Try again")
            alert.show()
            return
        }

        //prints the MKLocalSearchResponse with name, phoneNumber, placemark
        println(localSearchResponse)

        //Get latitude and longitude
        var newRecordLat = localSearchResponse.boundingRegion.center.latitude
        var newRecordLong = localSearchResponse.boundingRegion.center.longitude

        //How do I get the address, which is "placemark" in the MKLocalSearchResponse?
        var newRecordAddress = localSearchResponse.mapItems...???


        //store values to Parse
        self.latToParse = newRecordLat
        self.longToParse = newRecordLong



    }
```

Here is the documentation of [MKSearchResponse](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKLocalSearchResponse_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKLocalSearchResponse/mapItems)

And here is the documentation of [MKMapItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapItem_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapItem/phoneNumber)

Answer (score 1):

The error is misleading.  Nothing here has been deprecated.  You need to handle some optionals and a typecast:

**Swift 1.2**:

```
if let newRecordAddress = (localSearchResponse.mapItems.first as? MKMapItem)?.placemark {
    // use newRecordAddress
}
```

**Swift 2.0**:

```
if let newRecordAddress = localSearchResponse.mapItems.first?.placemark {
    // use newRecordAddress
}
```

Comment: @JoshOConnor, did that solve your problem? Please accept my answer if it did, or post your own answer if you solved it another way yourself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31488686/accessing-mklocalsearchresponse-item-swift