# Retrieve first 'mapItem' element from MKLocalSearch object in swift

Tags: swift, mklocalsearch

first I want to say I'm new to the swift language.

**My question almost mirrors this question:** [Accessing MKLocalSearchResponse item (swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31488686/accessing-mklocalsearchresponse-item-swift)

However, when I apply this to my similar looking code I get an error "Value of type 'MKLocalSearch' has no member 'mapItems'"

Like in the link above I want the first mapItems (mapItems[0]) result.
Can anybody help me?

Heres my code:

```
    let latitude = String(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)
    let longitude = String(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)

    var station1Unwrapped: String! = ""
    var station2Unwrapped: String! = ""

    var coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D!
    coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    var region: MKCoordinateRegion!
    region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coord, latitudinalMeters: 100, longitudinalMeters: 100);

    let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = "Train Station"
    request.region = region

    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
    search.start { response, error in
        guard let response = response else {
            print("There was an error searching for: \(String(describing: request.naturalLanguageQuery)) error: \(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        print("Inside function")

        let station1 = response.mapItems[0].name


    }

    var newLocVar = (search.mapItems[0] as! MKMapItem).name
    print(newLocVar)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `search` is `MKLocalSearch`, so it doesn't has property `mapItems`. If you want to print the `MKMapItem's name`, you should access the `mapItems` in the completion block, where you get access to the `response` which is `MKLocalSearch.Response`. The line you write `let station1 = response.mapItems[0].name` is perfectly correct and it contains the name of the first `mapItems` found

Comment: Thanks for your response qtingo, but how do I access map items from outside the block - I have other code there where I want to display the station name

Comment: Just moved the code inside the completion block xD thanks